# Matlab labeling, plots, legends

Tags: matlab, legend

How do I get my legend entry to have an underscore in the name without MATLAB thinking I want the underscore to mean subscript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to escape the underscore with a backslash `\` as `legend('foo\_bar')`

Answer (score 4):

One option, if you don't intend to use *any* TeX or LaTeX formatting for your legend strings, is to set the [`'Interpreter'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/text_props.html#Interpreter) for the legend object to `'none'`. There are two ways to do this:

```
legend({'foo_bar'},'Interpreter','none');  %# One line, labels in a cell array

%# OR...

hLegend = legend('foo_bar');        %# Create the legend, returning a handle
set(hLegend,'Interpreter','none');  %# Set the property
```

Comment: Setting `'Interpreter'` to `'none'` is the right approach if you don't know the contents of the string (e.g. a parameter such as a filename that contains underscores).